# How to fetch a row from one table and insert it into another table and get new PK value

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have two similar tables on different databases.

```
Database1/TableA

Database2/TableA
```

I want to fetch a row from one table and insert it into other table on other server. Like:

```
Database1/TableA
Id        State            Name
500        OH              John  [Fetch this row]

Database2/TableA
Id        State            Name
1          OH              John  [Insert and fetch PK '1']
```

I tried this using bulkcopy and it works fine.

But problem is I need to get PK from the new insert as I need to populate another child table.

Is there any better way to achieve this? Please on C# code, no database linking or SQL queries. Just C# solutions. Or if query can be used in C# code that is fine. Any working example code with Dataset or Datarow will be great help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get the row(s) from `Database.TableA`. You could for example use a `SqlDataAdapter` with a `DataTable` or a `SqlDataReader`.

[SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

You can use [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) to execute the insert command and retrieve the new ID in one query.

```
const String sqlSelect = "SELECT COL1,COl2,Col3 FROM TableA WHERE COL1=@COL1;"
const String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO TableA (COl2,Col3)VALUES (@Col2,@Col3);"
                       + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
using (var con1 = new SqlConnection(db1ConnectionString))
using (var con2 = new SqlConnection(db2ConnectionString))
{
    con1.Open();
    con2.Open();
    using(var selectCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, con1))
    {
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COL1", 4711);
        using (var reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                int newID;
                using (var insertCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlInsert, con2))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + reader.GetName(i), reader[i]);
                    }
                    newID = (int)insertCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to this is it possible for you to refer me to some code how to fetch data from the database? And why do i need to use DataTable for getting single row rather then DataRow?

Comment: I've thought that ypu wanted to retrieve multiple rows from TableA in DataBase1 since you've mentioned bulkcopy and DataSet. I've edited my answer to provide a complete sample.

Comment: Actually there are two tables. From first table (Table1/Database1) i need to get 1 row and insert it into table in database2/Table1. Then another table(Table2/Database1) i need to get 3 or 4 rows and insert it into Table2/database2 using the same primary key used for table1/Database2 insertion.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again - one more question. There is no way to do select * from tableA with id = 1 and do insert into tableA/database2 as all columns are same?

Comment: @NoviceMe: Yes, that works also, but normally you should avoid `*` but list all columns explicitely. I've edited my answer again to provide a dynamical approach which adds parameters to the insert-command automatically according to the columns in the sourcee row. Note that this is written from scratch without any tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Actually in this case i am pretty sure column names will match. Only this is i have over 15 columns, so if i do the query and add them individually it makes it a huge query. I am not sure if this is a right approach.

Comment: I am getting an error: Must declare the scalar variable "@Value".

Comment: Where do you get it? When you select the row from first database table or when you insert it into second? You need to provide that parameter in the query. For example `SELECT * FROM TableA Where Value=@Value`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16390/discussion-between-noviceme-and-tim-schmelter)